# Roslyn Code Issues And Fixes For Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, roslyn

I have experimented with Roslyn Code issues (and even blogged about them), but have lost touch with any progress being made on them.

The last I checked, code issues could only be used with Visual Studio 2013. Is this still the case, or is there a way to make it work with Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0):

No, there hasn't been any updates for Visual Studio 2012 in over two years and I don't believe Microsoft even distributes the September 2012 CTP anymore.

Even the support for Visual Studio 2013 is probably not good enough for production. There have been no more official releases of Roslyn for Visual Studio 2013 since April of last year.

On the old [Codeplex page](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) the following quote confirms this:

> (note: this VS 2013 preview is quite out of date, and is no longer updated)